# Duplicating Spring Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, web, web.xml

I want to clone my current spring web project on eclipse and create slightly different version. I try to do this because its easier than create new project and adding all previous project files to new project. However when I run the project it still runs the previous project's domain on the browser. [image]

```
On the browser I see http://localhost:8080/Product_Catelog_Spring/
instead of http://localhost:8080/Test_Product_Catelog_Spring/
```

---

**Web.xml for cloned project: Test_Product_Catelog_Spring**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Test_Product_Catelog_Spring</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.aspx</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>default.aspx</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Just use Spring Boot instead, and you won't need most of the configuration in the first place.